# How to import part of xml to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, xml, data-migration

I'd like to import some of the items in an large xml file to mysql table. Lets say the xml contains thousands of  items like:

```
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
```

But I need only 'TITLE' and 'YEAR' of each CD to be imported to mysql's cd table.

I know that there is a 'LOAD XML'  mysql 5.+ to get data from xml to mysql, but apparently it maps the whole xml, which is not what I need. So I appreciate your help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: What programming language do you use? I have a PHP sample solution if you use that.

Comment: @JohnConde, I have tried to find suitable tool for the job.

Comment: I use mostly python, bash, sql. PHP should be ok, even though not my ideal.

Comment: If you are comfortable with sql, then why not use the LOAD XML command  to load your file into a temporary table, grab the info you want, and drop it?

Comment: @abase You are right. That's the easiest way. I didn't notice that I could create a table just with the necessary columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks abase omment, I just figured out that the easiest way to import necessary fields from xml to mysql table is to use the built in Load XML feature of mysql, like:

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.xml' INTO TABLE  cds ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<CD>';
```

Where you previously created cds table by the columns that you need from file.xml.

Just notice that in mysql 5.5+ you need to add '--local-infile ' flag when you enter the mysql command line, otherwise you get an ERROR 1148.

Comment: Happy you found a solution!

Answer (score 3):

Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to load the XML and then loop through the values. My example uses `simplexml_load_string()` you can just as easily use [`simple_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

**Example**

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<CDS>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque2</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1986</YEAR>
</CD>
</CDS>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml as $cd) 
{
    // Your mysql functions for inserting goes here
    echo $cd->TITLE . "<br>";
    echo $cd->YEAR . "<br>";
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZC0E3i)

Hopefully that gives you a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

So you can have this approach to get the job done:

- Convert your big XML file with all elements into a smaller XML file with only needed element
  using XSLT transformation
- Than using XML parsers like SAXON, DOM or other parse the new small XML file
- Use some programming language that will do the parsing and database dumping part for you.
  For example if you plan to use java you can use concept called as JAXB to unmarshall your 
  XML to java objects and than populate them into database.

If you can share more information about your original XML and what elements you want from them I can post solution in JAVA for you.

Hope this will help you.