# Select what data to import from XML to mySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I need to import a really big XML file into my MySQL table. The problem is that I need to choose what data to input. For example the  XML is like this:

```
<FLIGHT>
<Airline>SAS</Airline>
<FlightNumber>1</FlightNumber>
<CommercialFlightNumber>SK1</CommercialFlightNumber>
<From>LLA</From>
<To>ARN</To>
<PreparedAt>2015/01/30 00:00</PreparedAt>
<Aircraft>LN-RGI</Aircraft>
<AircraftType>0</AircraftType>
<ClimbMode>1</ClimbMode>
<CruiseMode>100600</CruiseMode>
<DescentMode>1</DescentMode>
<InitAlt>MAX</InitAlt>
<StepClimb>-1</StepClimb>
<MTOW>-1</MTOW>
<MLW>-1</MLW>
<STD>2015/1/19 06:00</STD>
<STA>2015/1/19 07:30</STA>
<MaxPax>0</MaxPax>
<MaxCargo>0</MaxCargo>
<RandomPayload>0</RandomPayload>
<Type>0</Type>
<Repetative>1</Repetative>
<IsMaster>1</IsMaster>
<BeginDate>2015/02/04 00:00</BeginDate>
<EndDate>2015/04/30 23:59</EndDate>
<Days>1</Days>
<Baggage>-1</Baggage>
<Payload>-1</Payload>
<Notes>7388</Notes>
</FLIGHT>
```

But I only need the "CommercialFlightNumber", "From", "To", "Aircraft" and "Days". I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031286/4784140) answer and tried to put my information in a php file but the file got to big and the program crashed.. Is there anyway to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Parse this XML through XML parser and make it an array

Comment: This is a rather broad question

Comment: and when you say sql file, do you mean xml file?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I ment XML file, fixing that now

Comment: @SunilPachlangia How would I do that?

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

Comment: @gotqn how would I use that to put the information in a table?

Comment: @GustavPSvensson "...into my **SQL server** table". So you're using SQL Server right? If so then please remove `mysql` tag to avoid confusion. SQL XML handling function/syntax usually specific to each RDBMS

Comment: please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Look into SQL Server's `nodes()` :

> The nodes() method is useful when you want to shred an xml data type instance into relational data. It allows you to identify nodes that will be mapped into a new row. [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)]

Example for inserting only particular XML elements into a table :

```
declare @table TABLE(CommFlightNo varchar(10), 
                     [From] varchar(3), [To] varchar(3), 
                     Aircraft varchar(10), Days int)
declare @xml xml = '...xml posted in question....'


INSERT INTO @table
SELECT F.x.value('CommercialFlightNumber[1]', 'varchar(10)') as 'ComFlightNo'
      ,F.x.value('From[1]', 'varchar(3)') as 'From'
      ,F.x.value('To[1]', 'varchar(3)') as 'To'
      ,F.x.value('Aircraft[1]', 'varchar(10)') as 'Aircraft'
      ,F.x.value('Days[1]', 'int') as 'Days'
FROM @xml.nodes('//FLIGHT') as F(x)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5081)**

Comment: Thank you for your answere! Tho I got this error when I tried to run this:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @table

Comment: @GustavPSvensson my bad, I was too sure about `SQL Server` which turned out you're using `MySQL`, so this answer almost useless for you (except *maybe* the xpath part). As I said, each RDBMS has it's own way to handle XML.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by inserting the whole XML file into the table with the code

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.xml' INTO MY_TABLE
```

and then I just deleted the columns that I didn't needed.